# How to make sure uiview looks same in different ipads without using constraints

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiview, frame

in below example i have mentioned

-`view` (UIView which i will be displaying in both iPads).

-`parentView` (container UIView that will be same as iPads resolution).

-`parentViewOfIPadInWhichViewHasMade` : this is parentview of iPads in which view has been saved.this will be used when displaying view in different iPads.

function is i am saving view in iPad mini and saving it will store its frame information on server and when open app from iPad pro it will fetch those data from server and display view in iPad pro.

this is my expected output if view has been resized to fullscreen of iPad Pro and Fetched From iPad Mini

**iPad Pro 12.9 inch :**

- `view.size` (x : -25.0, y : -25.0, width : 1416.0, height : 874.0)
- `parentView.size` (x : 0.0, y : 0.0, width : 1366.0, height : 824.0)

**iPad Mini :**

- `view.size` : (x : -25.0,y : -25.0, width : 1074.0, height : 618.0)
- `parentView.size` : (x : 0.0, y : 0.0, width : 1024.0, height : 568.0)

to get this i have wrote below code in view did load.

```
viewX = parentView.frame.width * view.origin.x / parentViewOfIPadInWhichViewHasMade!.width

viewY = parentView.frame.height *  view!.origin.y / parentViewOfIPadInWhichViewHasMade!.height

viewWidth = parentView.frame.width * view!.frame.width / parentViewOfIPadInWhichViewHasMade!.width

viewHeight = parentView.frame.height * view!.frame.height / parentViewOfIPadInWhichViewHasMade!.height
```

note : can't fix size of view or use Constraint.

Comment: set the static width and height for the view which you want to display as same as in all ipad and set center of that view to center of the parent view

Comment: that view can be resized and moved anywhere in iPad screen. so can't fix anything.

Comment: Why you can not use constraints? That is exactly what you need...

Comment: because user can move view in screen anywhere and i am adding view from button from code and no constraint is added at first place. @J.Doe.

Comment: @Venkadesh  Thank you so much for your suggestion........... Thanks a lot

Comment: @J.Doe  Thank you so much for your suggestion........... Thanks a lot

Comment: Using constraints doesn't mean creating them in a storyboard / xib. You can add them to your views in code - in fact that is exactly what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a couple of ideas (before coding..):

1) your graphic/creative design must precisely consider the layout as a UX point of view. After this huge work you can start coding.

2) You can of course use code without using constraints. Asa programmer you cn prefer to do math instead of using mouse. But be careful: Using constraints is much more flexible and you can mix code too.

3) a pervasive and deep approach can be to implement layoutSubviews in every view..

example:

```
   override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()
    self.subTitle?.sizeToFit()
    self.callLabel?.sizeToFit()

    if(self.subTitle?.text == nil) {
        self.callLabel?.center.y = (self.titleLabel?.center.y)!
    }

}
```

but honestly for basic needs, better to use constraints, and eventually add an IBOutlet so you can control in code, for example height in custom view:

```
final func setH(Hconstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!){

    var h = Hconstraint!.constant
    if (.... add your test based on models, orientation...){
        h = H1
    }else{
        h = H2
    }

    Hconstraint.constant = h // re-apply height.
    self.setNeedsDisplay()  // to trigger redraw... seems needed in some cases...
}
```

(you can also add this code in controller.. but better to put it in custom view, so the logic is there..)

Comment: i will not be able to use constraint as user can add as many as view he/she wants. and on add button from where user is adding view, their are no constraint applied . so i prefer coding as i think i am near to solution but something is missing that i am not able to find.

Comment: ok, so the only way is to use layoutSubviews in custom views.

Comment: i think code you suggested will not help me as i will be having many uiview which can be moved to anywhere in screen. and i am already using custom view . i am setting its loaction in parentview by setting its frame. which can be resized or move by pan

Answer (score 0):

we need to use scale for this problem.

if we have saved view in ipad pro and opening in ipad mini than we need to set parentview's height and width from ipad pro parentview. and than scale down it to ipad mini parentview and calculate x and y cordinate change.